# Sitecore datetime to javascript Date object

Tags: javascript

Say please what is the best way to convert Sitecore datetime string (20170401T073000Z) to javascript Date object ?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356466/how-to-parse-20161114t000000z-to-datetime-object-in-sitecore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript equivalent of ISO date format used in Sitecore is `2017-04-01T07:30:00Z`.

You first need to convert from `20170401T073000Z` to 
`2017-04-01T07:30:00Z` and then create new Date object:

```
var dateString = "20170401T073000Z";

// change string to "2017-04-01T07:30:00Z";
var formattedDateString = dateString.substr(0, 4) 
    + "-" + dateString.substr(4, 2)
    + "-" + dateString.substr(6, 5)
    + ":" +  dateString.substr(11, 2)
    + ":" + dateString.substr(13, 3);

// create date obj with Timezone info
var dateObj = new Date(formattedDateString);
```